# Circle masked view animating too fast, and not tappable

Tags: ios, uiimageview, masking

I'm trying to make a **circle-masked image view with animated mask**, and played with different solutions. The example below does the job but I've got two problems with it:

1) Why is it that I **cannot make the image tappable**? Adding eg. a `UITapGestureRecognizer` does not work. My guess is that the mask prevents the touch actions being propagated to the lower level in the view hierarchy.

2) Animating the **mask is running very fast and I cannot adjust the duration** using `UIView` block animation

How can I solve these?

```
- (void) addCircle {
    // this is the encapsulating view
    //
    base = [[UIView alloc] init];
    //
    // this is the button background
    //
    base_bgr = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"c1_bgr.png"]];
    base_bgr.center = CGPointMake(60, 140);
    [base addSubview:base_bgr];
    //
    // icon image
    //
    base_icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"c1_ico.png"]];
    base_icon.center = CGPointMake(186*0.3/2, 182*0.3/2);
    base_icon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.3, 0.3);
    [base addSubview:base_icon];
    //
    // the drawn circle mask layer
    //
    circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    // Give the layer the same bounds as your image view
    [circleLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [base_icon frame].size.width,
                                      [base_icon frame].size.height)];
    // Position the circle
    [circleLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(186*0.3/2-7, 182*0.3/2-10)];
    // Create a circle path.
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
                          CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 70.0f, 70.0f)];
    // Set the path on the layer
    [circleLayer setPath:[path CGPath]];

    [[base layer] setMask:circleLayer];

    [self.view addSubview:base];
    base.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    base.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    base_bgr.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    base_icon.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    //
    // NOT working: UITapGestureRecognizer
    //
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapgesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapit:)];
    [base_icon addGestureRecognizer:tapgesture];

    //
    // BAD but WORKS :) properly positioned UIButton over the masked image
    //
    base_btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    base_btn.frame = CGRectMake(base.frame.origin.x, base.frame.origin.y, base_icon.frame.size.width, base_icon.frame.size.height);
    [base_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(tapit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:base_btn];
}
```

This is the tap handler, and here's the mask animation. Whatever number I tried in duration, it is animating fast - approximately 0.25 second, and I cannot adjust it.

```
- (void) tapit:(id) sender {
    //...
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^ {
                             [circleLayer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeScale(10.0, 10.0, 1.0)];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             // it is not necessary if I manage to make the icon image tappable
                             base_btn.frame = [base convertRect:base_icon.frame toView:self.view];  
                         }];
    }    
}
```

Comment: If Base is not getting touch, how would tapit get called in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) touches are not propagated down from `base` because it's initiated without a frame, so its frame will be CGRectZero. Views don't get touch events that start outside of their bounds. Simply set a valid frame on `base` that includes entire tap target.

2) `setTransform:` on a layer invokes an implicit animation which uses Core Animation's default duration of 0.25 (you guessed it right :)). The best solution would be to use `CABasicAnimation` instead of `UIView`-based animation. Something like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
scaleAnimation.toValue = @(10.0f);
scaleAnimation.duration = 2;
[circleLayer addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:nil];
```

Note: by default, `CABasicAnimation` will remove itself from a layer when complete and the layer will snap back to old values. You can prevent it by for example setting that animation's `removedOnCompletion` property to `NO` and removing it yourself later using `CALayer`'s `removeAnimationForKey:` method (just set a key instead of passing `nil` wheen adding the animation), but that depends on what exactly you want to accomplish with this.

Comment: Tested and works, thx! My experience related keeping the CABasicAnimation last phase is that I also had to include fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;